# The Citation of Imam Suyuti in Qu'ran 17:56?

Tags: quran, hadith, tafseer

I was reading Suyuti's Tafsir and i came across this
وأخْرَجَ اِبْنُ أبِي شَيْبَةَ، وابْنُ جَرِيرٍ، وابْنُ المُنْذِرِ، وابْنُ أبِي حاتِمٍ، وابْنُ مَرْدُويَهْ، عَنِ اِبْنِ عَبّاسٍ في قَوْلِهِ: ﴿فَلا يَمْلِكُونَ كَشْفَ الضُّرِّ عَنْكُمْ﴾ . قالَ: عِيسى وأُمُّهُ وعُزَيْرٌ.

I see he quoted Ibn Abu Shaybah but i cannot find the Narration anywhere in The musannaf ibn abi shayba? Can someone confirm that this quote is legit?

Comment: It has been recorded by Ibn Jarir (Tabari), see [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/7798/26676#p1). I could not find it in the musannaf.

Comment: First of all there are two brothers known as Ibn Abi Shaybah one of them is Abu Bakr born 156 A.H. author of al-Mosannaf and al-Musnad in hadith the other Abu al-Hassan born 159 A.H. is as a-Dhahabi said a leader of the hufadh and author of al-Musnad and a tafsir that is said to have gotten lost it is mainly this scholar who has been the teacher of al-Bukhari and Muslim, but they also quoted his brother. So as-Suyuti could have meant one of these four sources.

Answer (score 2):

Among the books listed in a book entitled:
 <sup>In the following I'll be translating from Arabic language. As these translations are of my own take them with the necessary care</sup>

> أسماء الكتب والأجزاء الإسلامية المفقودة
> The names of the Islamic books and volumes lost.

You may find a book called: **Tafsir ibn abi Shaybah: تفسير ابن أبي شيبة**.

However the author or editor Hikmat Bashir Yaseen حكمت بشير ياسين didn't add any proper reference or information to the author (in some cases a date of death of the author etc.  was added).
A strange thing about this book which is mainly a list, is that the copy I found on the net starts with #4XX and some of the listed books at least seem to be  existing like the Tafsir of abi Hathim (I'm not sure whether this existing book is the full work of the author). But for the Tafsir of ibn Abi Shabah this is only a confirmation of information I've read in many threads.

Now when we check the Islamic history and biographies of Muslim scholars we may find a couple of scholars who are called: ibn abi Shaybah. I'll just address those who seem most likely to be referred to in a-Durr al-Manthur of imam as-Suyuti:

The most known among them is 'Abdullah [ibn abi Shaybah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Abi_Shaybah) ابن أبي شيبة also known as abu Bakr ibn abi Shaybah the author of the known al-Mosannaf. He was set equal to scholars such as imam Ahmad, [Ishaaq ibn Rahawayh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishaq_ibn_Rahwayh) and ['Ali ibn al-Madini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_ibn_al-Madini) by imam a-Dhahabi in his book Siyar a'laam an-Nubalaa' [سير أعلام النبلاء](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=1978&idfrom=0&idto=0&flag=1&bk_no=60&ayano=0&surano=0&bookhad=0):

> وهو من أقران أحمد بن حنبل ، وإسحاق بن راهويه ، وعلي ابن المديني في السن والمولد والحفظ.
> He is one of the companions of Ahmad bin Hanbal, Ishaq bin Rahwayh, and Ali Ibn al-Madini in age, birth and memorization.

But according to imam a-Dhahabi in his siyar a'alaam an-Nubala' two of his brothers were also scholars 'Othman [عثمان بن أبي شيبة](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B9%D8%AB%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%8A_%D8%B4%D9%8A%D8%A8%D8%A9) (see also in [سير أعلام النبلاء](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=1992&idfrom=0&idto=0&flag=1&bk_no=60&ayano=0&surano=0&bookhad=0) he was among the teachers of al-Bukhari, Muslim and the authors of the Sunan ibn Majah and abu Dawud, and al-Bukhari often quoted him) also known as abu al-Hassan and al-Qassim (who was declared as da'if by a-Dhahabi) as stated in the biography of abu Bakr:

> أخو الحافظ عثمان بن أبي شيبة ، والقاسم بن أبي شيبة الضعيف . فالحافظ إبراهيم بن أبي بكر هو ولده ، والحافظ أبو جعفر محمد بن عثمان هو ابن أخيه ، فهم بيت علم . وأبو بكر أجلهم .
> The brother of Al-Hafidh 'Othman ibn Abi Shaybah, and Al-Qasim ibn Abi Shaybah, the weak. The Hafidh Ibrahim ibn Abi Bakr is his son, and the Hafidh Abu Jaafar Muhammad bin 'Othman is his nephew, they are a house of knowledge. Abu Bakr, their greatest among them.

That's why usually the reference ibn abi Shaybah is referring to him.

Both abu Bakr and abu al-Hassan were known as hufadh of hadith and also authors of Tafsir books.
In the above linked biography of abu Bakr you may read:

> عبد الله بن محمد بن القاضي أبي شيبة إبراهيم بن عثمان بن خواستى الإمام العلم ، سيد الحفاظ ، وصاحب الكتب الكبار " المسند " و " المصنف " ، " و**التفسير** " ، أبو بكر العبسي مولاهم الكوفي .
> 'Abdullah ibn Muhammad ibn al-Qadi Abi Shaybah Ibrahim ibn Othman ibn Khwasti  the imam al-'Alam (the knowledgable) , the master of preservation, and the author of the great books “Al-Musnad” and “Al-Musannaf” and “**at-Tafisr**”, Abu Bakr Al-'Absi, their mawla Al-Kufi.

While n that of abu al-Hassan you may read:

> هو الإمام الحافظ الكبير **المفسر** ، أبو الحسن ، عثمان بن محمد بن القاضي أبي شيبة إبراهيم بن عثمان بن خواستى العبسي مولاهم الكوفي ، صاحب التصانيف ، وأخو الحافظ أبي بكر .
> He is the great Imam al-Hafidh the **Mufassir**, Abu al-Hasan, 'Othman ibn Muhammad ibn al-Qadi, Abu Shaybah Ibrahim ibn Othman ibn Khwasti al-'Absi, their mawla al-Kufi, the author of the compilations, and the brother of al-Hafidh Abu Bakr.

Further abu Bakr had beside al-Mosannaf another book of hadith entitled: al-Musnad the ebook copy of it that I found doesn't seem to cover the quoted hadith either.

However as stated above it is most likely that as-Suyuti meant him and I'd assume that his book (most likely the tafsir) or at least its content was still existing or memorized at the time of as-Suyuti.